# create r vector with names

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this output that I can create with static inputs:

```
t1 = c("dog"="dog","cat"= "cat")
t1

Results:
     dog   cat 
    "dog" "cat"
```

How can I create those same results with only the t$animal character vector below

```
t = data.frame(animal = c("dog","cat"))
c(t$animal =t$animal)  # this does not work
```

Comment: t = data.frame(animal = c("dog","cat")); rownames(t) <- t$animal

Comment: oh sory you tried to do it transposed, than: t1 <- c("dog","cat"); names(t1) <- t1

Comment: user2821029, if you want names *within* the frame vector, you need to state as such ... and I don't know that there's an easy (or good) way to do it. What are you ultimately trying to do here? I see no programmatic nor aesthetic advantage to having those names.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to character and then use `names<-` (or `setNames`):

```
ch <- as.character(unlist(t))
names(ch) <- ch
ch
##   dog   cat 
## "dog" "cat"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setNames`

```
t2 <- setNames(t$animal, t$animal)
t2

#dog cat 
#dog cat
```

**data**

```
t <- data.frame(animal = c("dog","cat"))
```

Comment: But the vector `t$animal` will still have no names. `t1 <- setNames(t$animal, t$animal)` would work.

Comment: that doesnt seem to work setNames(t$animal ,t$animal) . aftersetnames t shows   animal X.cat.
1    dog    cat

Comment: @RuiBarradas, the question *seems* to be about assigning names programmatically, given the column of a frame.

Comment: @r2evans Yes, I understood that. The df column will be used to set the names of another vector, not of the df's column vector.

Comment: @user2821029 Is your data frame really `t = data.frame(animal = "dog","cat")` or that was a typo and you meant `t = data.frame(animal = c("dog","cat"))` ?